# If I get a Python instance of a Qt widget, is there any way to export/replicate it?

Tags: python, qt, maya

I've just found how to integrate Maya's internal UI into Qt, but their code has some checks that make it difficult to define any widgets without creating a separate Maya window.

As I am able to grab a Qt instance of the widget after this window has been created, is there anything I'd be able to read from this, that would allow me to bypass the `pm.*` wrapper to directly create the Qt object?

I've dug through Maya's python code and there's no reference to a lot of their widgets, so I'd imagine they're all defined in C++.

Here's a brief example of how to create the widget in Maya, then move it into the Qt window:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omUI
import pymel.core as pm

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # Normal Qt stuff
        parent = wrapInstance(int(omUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()), QtWidgets.QWidget)
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)

        # Build a Maya window
        with pm.window():
            with pm.frameLayout(label='Buttons', collapsable=True) as mayaWidget:
                with pm.columnLayout():
                    pm.button()

        # Get the Qt instance of the widget
        widget = pm.uitypes.toQtObject(mayaWidget)

        # Add it to the layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

Window().show()
```

Every single UI element is built into a `QWidget`, so there's nothing as obvious as custom classes.

Just to make clear, I'm interested in the process behind this and perhaps a way to do it to any widget that's defined by a wrapper, I'm not looking specifically at `frameLayout`.

Comment: Please take a look to [**mcve**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question. **Quote:** *"Copy the code from your question into a new file or project, then run it. If it doesn't run for you, then it won't run for anyone else."*

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do....

Comment: @PatrickTrentin, the code would have run from any Qt window, all it needed was to be given a layout. I've updated the question anyway, to be honest I've now gone down a different route of dealing with it, but I am curious if what I've asked is possible.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to use the unreliable, complicated maya UI commands to create UI elements instead of the more logical, more reliable and easier to use original QT widgets?

Comment: Sadly yes haha, there's no official Qt counterparts for a few of the UI commands. In my current case for example, I'm needing the functionality of `shelfLayout` so users can post scripts for each other. I'm working on designing a much better tool, but it's such a large project that I'm looking for a quick alternative for the time being. I'd imagine all of Maya's widgets are proper Qt widgets beneath it all, they just don't seem to open anything up for you.